# Is it possible to install Dynamic Languages Toolkit together with ShellEd?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, mylyn

I'd like to be able to edit both Ruby and Bash files natively in Eclipse Keppler. I also need Mylyn. The problem is, that installing ShellEd triggers dependency conflict:

[image]

Is there any way to use ShellEd together with Mylyn/Ruby? Is there a reason to issue a bug on ShellEd?

---

edit: This is a list of my istalled plugins:

[image]

Comment: What do you see on the previous screen, or if you select "Show original error..." above?

Comment: @E-Riz I guess you want to take a look at the versions of the installed plugins. I've updated the question.

Comment: OK, I updated my answer based on the information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version of the DLTK Ruby tools you have installed is 2.0.0 which is very old (the current version in the Kepler repo is 5.0.0). ShellEd declares that it requires DLTK version 4.0.0 or higher, so you just need to upgrade to the latest DLTK Ruby version. That should be easy to do by selecting the Kepler repo when doing **Install New Software**.

[image]

It looks like the DLTK Mylyn Integration feature does not exist any more so you'll have to let it be uninstalled. That doesn't affect Mylyn in general, which should remain intact.